# How to delay the ssh command prompt?

Tags: ssh

For testing purpose i am trying to add some delay to show the command prompt after the ssh is successful!

```
# ssh root@ip
Using username "root".
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Last login: ....
test:~ #
```

I would like to get the command prompt (not the password question) to be shown after 10s!

I did one try with changing the PS1 with adding sleep 10, this seems to work in general but when the ssh command uses `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5` then this solution is not working!

Solution for PS1:

1. modify the /etc/profile
2. add one line `export PS1="\e[31m\]\e[1m\] \h:\w # \[\e[m\]\$(sleep 10)"`
3. then `source /etc/profile`
   But as said this is not working with `-o ConnectTimeout`!

Any other idea?

Comment: Do you want a delay just once upon login, or before _every_ command?

Comment: You are right just once upon login! Yes, the other solution with PS1 will bring a delay with every command and during login but not if -o ConnectTimeout is used!

Comment: Instead of modifying the command prompt, just put a sleep command as a line by itself in your `~/.profile`.

Comment: NICE, that is so simple and it is working also with the -o ConnectTimeout! Thanks

Comment: @AFSHIN Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the command prompt, just put a sleep command as a line by itself in your `~/.profile`.